# Salesforce Marketing Cloud : HTML Block in triggered send over REST API running into 4000 character restriction

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, triggered-send

I'm attempting to send an email over marketing cloud using the REST API from our ecommerce platform. Most of the data is easy to send over using SubscriberAttributes.

However, there is some data, as you can imagine for ecommerce, that is tabular in nature (for example, order line items in an order table) that can't be parsed over in SFMC to my knowledge, and thus must be passed as HTML from our ecommerce application.

This is fine, as its the same way with most email marketing platforms, however, I'm running into the 4000 character limit, which we quickly overflow for any order with multiple line items.

I know I can chunk the HTML data into 4000 character blocks and continue to send it over through the subscriber attributes, but this is pretty unclean.

Is there a better way to pass larger amounts of data through triggered sends?

Thanks,

Emil

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Do understand that this issue is VARCHAR2, as 4000 is the limit.  So, we maybe have to do some "creative" stuff. 
I would use AMPscript to do it.  I would put an httpget call in my email ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httpget.htm) to do an outbound call to a route on my end, which would give the text to parse.   I don't think the variables in AMPscript are going to have this limit, but it if does, you can do it a few times to different routes..

Comment: It's a creative solution, but it still isn't very clean.  Doing so would essentially make an API call from our email service just to pull in order history. Having an open endpoint like that (unless we pass some authentication credentials from the email server) for what a customer bought would violate Sarbanes Oxley. To make it secure would be overly complicated. I ended up creating 99 profile attributes and am chunking them unfortunately.